# System package name

Tags: android

Does anybody know what the package name for **"Android system"** is?

My app populates a spinner control with installed packages, I've created a function that removes all the apps I do not wan't to see in this list. I've removed all the guff but I'm left with one app "Android system".

If somebody could please provide me with the package name for "Android System" I can then remove it from my spinner!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Worked it out, It's just **"android"** if anyone else finds this useful.

Comment: To avoid comparison with a String literal, it would be nice to know eactly where this is defined.